# Reductions between LIS and LCS

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, reference-request, dynamic-programming, strings

Given an oracle that returns both the length and the subsequence for the Longest Increasing Subsequence of a given input $A$ of $n$ elements $\text{LIS}(A,n)$, can one use a polynomial number of calls to it to find the *length* of the Longest Common Subsequence of two sequences $A$ and $B$ ($\text{LCS}(A,B)$)? If so, how few calls can we query the LIS oracle in order to find the length of $\text{LCS(A,B)}$?

Alternatively, given an oracle for finding both the subsequence and length of the Longest Common Subsequence between two sequences, it's easy to find $\text{LIS}(A)$: Given a sequence $A$, sort $A$ into $A'$, and calculate $\text{LCS}(A,A')$.

This question is prompted by the fact that there are $O(n\log n)$ algorithms for LIS but not LCS. On a separate note, are there any results comparing the hardness of the two problems or giving a superlinear/quadratic lower bound to LCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given an oracle that returns both the length and the subsequence for the Longest Increasing Subsequence of a given input $A$ of $n$ elements $\text{LIS}(A,n)$, can one use a polynomial number of calls to it to find the *length* of the Longest Common Subsequence of two sequences $A$ and $B$ ($\text{LCS}(A,B)$)? If so, how few calls can we query the LIS oracle in order to find the length of $\text{LCS(A,B)}$?

Well, we can find $\text{LCS}(A,B)$ without any call to the oracle since we can just run any algorithm that finds $\text{LCS}(A,B)$ such as brutal force or [a solution by dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Solution_for_two_sequences).

What you intended to ask was how much we can reduce the time-complexity of algorithms that find $\text{LCS}(A,B)$ if the oracle is available. The time-complexity will consist of two parts. One part comes from ordinary operations, and the other part comes from the calls to the oracle. There are two questions here.

**Question one.** Can we use less ordinary operations (asymptotically) with the availability of the oracle?

**Question two.**  If we can, how few calls to the oracle are needed to lower the complexity of the ordinary operations?

#### When one of $A$ and $B$ consists of distinct elements

Suppose the elements in $A$ are distinct. Here is an algorithm that employs the oracle. The idea of the algorithm is that if we regard the natural order of elements in $A$ according to the indices as defining a strictly increasing order, a common subsequence of $A$ and $B$ is exactly an increasing subsequence of $B$.

1. Keeping $A$ intact, sort $A$ into a new sequence $\alpha$.
2. Initialize a new sequence $I$.
3. For $i$ from 0 to size($B$) exclusive, try finding the index $j$ such that $A[j]$ is $B[i]$. If found, append $\alpha[j]$ to $I$.
4. Return the length that is returned by the oracle given sequence $I$.

There are two ways to implement step 2.

- If the elements in $A$ and $B$ can be totally ordered, we can sorted the elements in $A$, keeping track of each element's index in $A$. Then a binary search can find that index $j$.
- Construct a hash set whose elements are $(A[i],i)$ for all $i$, where the hash depends only on $A[i]$. Then we can use the hash set to find that index $j$.

So an answer to question one and two is that we can use a single call to the oracle to lower the complexity of the ordinary operations from $O(nm)$ to

- $O(n\log n + m \log n)$ when $m\gg\log n$ or
- $O(m)$ if the operation of finding an element in a hashset is considered $O(1)$.

Here $n$ is the number of distinct elements in one array and $m$ is the number of the elements in the other array.

#### When both $A$ and $B$ contain duplicate elements

It is not clear how we can take advantage of the oracle in order to reach a positive answer to question one. Instead, here is a conditional hardness result.

It is not possible to find $LCS(A,B)$ in time $O(n^{2 - \epsilon})$ for any positive constant $\epsilon$ where $n$ is the length of $A$ and $B$, if we can assume [*the strong exponential time hypothesis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis). This is shown in [*Tight Hardness Results for LCS and Other Sequence Similarity Measures*](https://doi.org/10.1109/FOCS.2015.14) by Amir Abboud, Arturs Backurs and Virginia Vassilevska Williams, 2015.

Comment: If the oracle can returns the length for the Longest Increasing Subsequence of a given **integer** sequence, then the algorithm can be simplified by **a**) appending $j$ to $I$ in step 3 and **b**) removing step 1.